# ClusterRole exists and cannot be imported into the current release?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to install the same chart two times in the same cluster in two different namespaces. However I am getting this error:

```
Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: ClusterRole "nfs-provisioner" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" must equal "namespace2": current value is "namespace1"
```

As I understood cluster roles suposed to be independet from the namespace, so I found this contradictory. We are using helm3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I decided to provide a Community Wiki answer that may help other people facing a similar issue.
I assume you want to install the same chart multiple times but get the following error:

```
Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: ClusterRole "<CLUSTERROLE_NAME>" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: ...
```

First, it's important to decide if we really need `ClusterRole` instead of `Role`.
As we can find in the [Role and ClusterRole documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole):

> If you want to define a role within a namespace, use a Role; if you want to define a role cluster-wide, use a ClusterRole.

Second, we can use the variable name for `ClusterRole` instead of hard-coding the name in the template:

For example, instead of:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: clusterrole-1
...
```

Try to use something like:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.clusterrole.name }}
...
```

Third, we can use the `lookup` function and the `if` control structure to skip creating resources if they already exist.

Take a look at a simple example:

```
$ cat clusterrole-demo/values.yaml
clusterrole:
  name: clusterrole-1

$ cat clusterrole-demo/templates/clusterrole.yaml
{{- if not (lookup "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1" "ClusterRole" "" .Values.clusterrole.name) }}

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.clusterrole.name }}
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
{{- end }}
```

In the example above, if `ClusterRole` `clusterrole-1` already exits, it won’t be created.

Comment: Thanks. I still not getting why it is crying about the specific namespace... But I guess that is just a misleading error message.

Comment: Yes, I still get both errors at the same time too just as @KilyenOrs did (specific namespace and existing ClusterRole resource).

Answer (score 1):

`ClusterRole` sets permission across your Kubernetes cluster, not for particular namespace. It think you misunderstand with `Role`. You can see further information of the differences between `ClusterRole` and `Role` here, [Role and ClusterRole](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole).

```
A Role always sets permissions within a particular namespace; when you create a Role, you have to specify the namespace it belongs in.

ClusterRole, by contrast, is a non-namespaced resource. The resources have different names (Role and ClusterRole) because a Kubernetes object always has to be either namespaced or not namespaced; it can't be both.
```

Comment: "Unable to continue with install: ClusterRole"

Comment: The error states very clearly "CusterrRole"

Comment: As I see your question summary, it looks like asking just only for ClusterRole. If you cannot succeed to install again after removing the existing ClusterRole, you had better create new ticket focused the helm error messages. I'm not famliar with Helm.

Comment: You need to modify the chart to create namespace-scoped `Role` resources rather than global `ClusterRole`.  That's not Helm-specific, except that it keeps track of the Kubernetes objects it's trying to install.

Comment: @KilyenOrs Does this answer your question ?